# How can I simplify an if..else statement when parsing an array

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a function that filters an array of objects and reduces to one String. The array has this format:

```
[Person(destination: “city”, surname: [“sur”, “name”]]
```

This is the function that filters the persons to find the surname by a certain name.

And I have three states of name: "john", "paul", "james". I want to verify if each name exists and to do something with his surname. How can I do this without using if...else. I don't like how it looks with all this if's.

```
 enum Destination: String, RawRepresentable {
    case city
    case rural
    case both
}


func findPerson(person: persons, type: Destination) -> String? {
        let surname = persons.filter{ $0.destination == type.rawValue}.reduce("") { id, element in
            return element.details.joined(separator: " ")
        }
         return surname
    }


func findPersons(person: persons) {
        // Also I want to verify if is not null the string that i receive

        if let city = self.findPerson(person: person, type: .city) {
            self.handleCity(type: city)
        }
        if let rural = self.findPerson(person: person, type: .rural) {
            self.handleRural(type: rural)
        }
        if let both = self.findPerson(person: person, type: .both) {
            self.handleBoth(type: both)
        }

    }
```

Comment: There is no if...else in your current code. Is your question about why the current code isn’t working? Either way, it would be helpful to have an example of what output you’re expecting from a given input.

Comment: Code, currently provided, doesn't even compiles. Can you provide [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score -1):

```
 enum Destination: String, RawRepresentable {
    case city
    case rural
    case both

 static let all : [Destination] = [
            .city,
            .rural,
            .both
        ]


 func findPersons(person: persons) {
        // Also I want to verify if is not null the string that i receive

        for destination in Destination.all{
            if let findPerson(person, type: destination){
                self.handleCity(type: destination.rawValue)
            }
        }

    }
```